# Логические операторы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Что значит эта запись?

```py
if a == b and c:
    #do something
```

Это значит если `a` равно `b` и равно `с`, то сделать что-то?

Или если `a` равно `b` и выполняется условие `c`, то сделать что-то?

И можно ли писать иначе? Например, так:

```py
if a == b and a == c or a == d:
    #do something
```

Comment: Эта запись равносильна `if (a == b) and (bool(c) == True)`

Comment: @andreymal, а True разве не к bool относится? То есть имеется разница как писать c==true или bool(c)?  Если да, то объясните пожалуйста как?

Comment: Никакой разницы, `c` и `bool(c)` и `bool(c) == True` внутри if'а будут значить одно и то же

Comment: @andreymal, окей. спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @abby, распишу более подробно: Если 'c' не принадлежит к логическому типу, то оно может быть истинным, но не равняться True. Например, любая непустая строка не равна True, но при этом bool('Непустая строка') уже равняется True. В логических выражениях проверяется именно истинность значения, а не его равенство с True. Поэтому внутри условия выражения 'c', 'bool(c)' и 'bool(c) == True' всегда равносильны. А вот выражение 'c==True' уже имеет совсем другой смысл.

Comment: `a == b and a == c or a == d` можно заменить на `a in [b, c, d]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **`if a == b and c:`** означает, что `a` равно `b` и `c` правда. А само выражение, по сути, разворачивается в `if a == b and bool(c):`.

   Метод [bool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) очень умный и возвращает `True` или `False` для любых объектов.
   Например:

   ```
   print(bool(1))         # True
   print(bool(123))       # True
   print(bool(""))        # False
   print(bool("abc"))     # True
   print(bool([]))        # False
   print(bool([1, 2, 3])) # True
   print(bool(0))         # False
   print(bool(None))      # False
   ...
   ```

   Т.е. если объект условно пустой, то `False`, иначе `True`

   Чтобы эта магия работала у объектов должен быть переопределен магический метод `def __bool__(self):`, пример:

   ```
   class Foo:
       def __init__(self, bool_val=True):
           self.bool_val = bool_val

       def __bool__(self):
           print('bool_val:', self.bool_val)
           return self.bool_val

   c = Foo(bool_val=True)
   bool(c)     # bool_val: True

   c = Foo(bool_val=True)
   if c: pass  # bool_val: True

   c = Foo(bool_val=False)
   if c: pass  # bool_val: False
   ```

   Как видно в `bool(...)` или в `if ...` будет вызван `__bool__` и по нему определится можно ли считать, что объект `True` или `False`
2. **`if a == b and a == c or a == d:`** тут порядок выстроен по приоритетам (от большего к меньшему): `NOT`, `AND`, `OR`. Т.е. сначала идет `and`, потом `or`, а если бы у вас был `if ... not c`, то сначала `not` т.е. инвертирование.

   Добавлю скобки, чтобы было нагляднее:

   ```
   if (a == b and a == c) or a == d:
   ```

   Кст, если `a == b and a == c` вернут `True`, то проверки `... or a == d` не будет (т.е. при `or` если одна часть `True`, то без разницы, что в другой -- все-равно будет `True`):

   ```
   def a(): print('a'); return True
   def b(): print('b'); return True
   def c(): print('c'); return True
   def d(): print('d'); return True

   if a() == b() and a() == c() or a() == d():
       pass
   ```

   Выведет:

   ```
   a
   b
   a
   c
   ```

Comment: Можно позанудствовать немного? `bool(Foo(bool_val=[]))` сломается)

Comment: @andreymal, `TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned list` :)

Comment: @gil9red, класс. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваше второе предположение верно, а именно:

   > если a = b и выполняется условие c, то что-то
2. Да, так `if a == b and a == c or a == d:` писать можно
3. Советую почитать про приоритет операторов Python [здесь](https://qa-help.ru/questions/prioritet-logicheskikh-operatorov-not-and-or-v-python)

Comment: то есть это равносильно следующему: если `a`== `b` и `a` == `c` или `a`== `d`, то что-то. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @abby Учитывайте приоритет операторов, И более приоритетно, чем ИЛИ, т.е. можно переписать так: `((a == b) and (a == c)) or (a == d)`, то есть если либо одновременно `a`=`b` и `a`=`c`, либо `a`=`d`, то что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Второе. Это означает "если ((`а` равно `b`) и (`с` истинно))".

> И можно ли писать так?

Так писать можно, но это уже совсем другое условие.

Comment: Проверки `if c` и `if c == True` разные. `if c` это `if bool(c)`, т.е. если `c = [1, 2, 3]`, то `if c` пройдет проверку, а `if c == True` нет

Comment: @gil9red, а как понять что использовать. можете пример написать подробнее? Спасибо

Comment: @gil9red Да, точно, не подумал.